# Which is correct "your" or "their" when combining questions?

Tags: word-usage, questions, pronouns, personal-pronouns

What is ***one*** to do when they are locked out and therefore unable to access the Slack support channel, or have to email sysadmin from an address other than ***your*** work one?

I came across the above statement. I understand what they mean, but this sounds weird to me. First, they start with the word "one" and end with "your", Is this a proper usage? I'd would tend to use "their" instead of "your".

Is this because they have combined two questions?

Comment: This is not correct usage, it should be "their". You're correct. With hypothetical questions like this, we often use either "you" (not necessarily meaning anyone involved is in that scenario, but asking what you would do hypothetically), or we use "one". If it's "one" then the pronoun should be "they". Alternatively, you could say "what are **you** to do when **you** are locket out..." and the meaning is the same.

Comment: My guess is that because it's a long sentence, the writer lost track of which hypothetical pronoun he or she was using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In American English, "one's" and "oneself" are often replaced with other pronouns (traditionally "his" and "himself"; in modern American English, "their" and "themselves").

In British English, "one's" and "oneself" are mandatory where appropriate, so you can't mix "one" with "his"/"their" - you must use the appropriate forms of "one":

> What is **one** to do when **one** is locked out and therefore unable to access the Slack support channel, or when **one** has to email sysadmin from an address other than **one's** work one?

This can sound a bit stilted; the alternative is to use "you", but you can't mix and match - it has to be "you" throughout:

> What can **you** do when **you're** locked out and therefore unable to access the Slack support channel, or when **you** have to email sysadmin from an address other than **your** work one?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a lack of gender neutral pronouns. The traditional solution was that because (*she* / *he*), (*her* / *his*), (*her* / *him*) enjoy a (**marked** / **unmarked**) relationship similar to (*lioness* / *lion*) as described in the second paragraph about [markedness](http://www.analytictech.com/mb119/markedne.htm), the male pronoun was used when the intent was to refer to both males and females.

About 20 years ago(?), to promote gender equality, the **markedness** property of gender pronouns began to be removed from the language. But some people still sometimes use male pronouns as gender neutral.

Always saying "he or she", "her or him" and "her or his" is most gender neutral, but cumbersome. One alternative is to say "one." Another is to use second person "you" and "your." Another alternative is to use the third person plural pronouns, "they", "them", and "their." While all three are gender neutral, the antecedent it implied to be plural. Despite this, native speakers regularly use third person plural pronouns even if the antecedent is singular.

While "you" and "your" are gender neutral, second person pronouns should not be used in formal writing. To promote gender equality, the markedness property cannot be used. This leaves the following best option in my opinion:

> What is one to do when locked out and therefore unable to access the Slack support channel or one to do when one has to email a sysadmin from an address other than a work address.

**using markedness**

> What is one to do when locked out and therefore unable to access his Slack support channel, or one to do when he has to email a sysadmin from an address other than his work address.

Comment: This was a great answer until your suggested rephrases. That "or one to do" doesn't make sense there; just "or" is fine.